# how to get resource using xmpp jidstr iOS sdk

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for xmpp. i am trying to get the resource for a particular JID string (venu@xx.in).

I using the below code

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"userJID:%@",user.jidStr);

XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject* userResource = (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject*)[user resourceForJID:[user.jid bareJID]];
NSLog(@"userResource:%@",userResource);
```

but the problem is userResource is returning null.

Is there any other way to resource for venu@xx.in . which is supposed to be like venu@xx.in/(userResource).

Comment: did you find any solution, I am also facing same issue.I need when user is offline then i want resource name but it is showing null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually get resource information associated with a bare JID from the presence you have received from each of the 0 or more devices currently connected for that JID.  If the contact is online with multiple devices, there will be multiple resources associated with the user.  The "most available" resource, otherwise known as the "primary resource" is likely to be the one you want.  `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` has a `primaryResource` method that will give you a `XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject`.  Try this (untested):

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *resource = [[[user primaryResource] jid] resource];
```

Comment: But i got **nil** while other user is offline on device.

Answer (score 0):

The resource for 'venu@xx.in' *is* missing.
JIDs have three parts, roughly speaking (read RFC6122 for the formal/correct version) the bit before the @ (localpart or sometimes userpart), the bit from the @ until the / (domainpart) and bit after the / (resourcepart). Either the localpart or the resourcepart may be missing. A JID with all these bits is a 'full' JID (e.g. venu@xx.in/wheeee) and a JID without the resource is a 'bare' JID (e.g. venu@xx.in).

Comment: Thanks kev for the reply , and explaining me resource and domain.I have corrected the code.Still having the same problem.    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"userJID:%@",user.jidStr);
    
    XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject* userResource = (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject*)[user resourceForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[user.jid resource]]];
    NSLog(@"userResource:%@",userResource);  userResource is still returning null